# codeigniter join query issue in email

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My Codeigniter join query is not work. In a function just try to match RC code in users table and get email, this function is properly work, next target is match email id from article table and get article its work properly, but ill try to join the users table and article table beacause i need to get the users firstname & lastname from users table, I don't know is that right way or not, check my code below. Controller Part :

```
  public function user_article()
{   

    $rc=$_GET['rc'];
    $data['title'] = "User Article";        
    if ($this->session->userdata ('is_logged_in')){
        $data['profile']=$this->model_users->profilefetch();
        $data['results']=$this->article_m->u_article($_GET);
        $this->load->view('sd/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('sd/user_article', $data);
        $this->load->view('sd/footer', $data);
    } 
    else {

    }
}
```

My Model :

```
  function u_article($rc)
    {  
        $query=$this->db->select('email')->where('rc',$rc['rc'])->get('users');

        $result=$query->result_array();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row_array(); 
            $array = array ('email' => $row['email'], 'a.status' => '1');   
            $query1=$this->db->select('a.id,title,a.status,description,image,a.email,tags,postdate,firstname,lastname,rc')->join('users u','u.email = a.email','left')->where($array)->get('articles a');

            if ($query1->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query1->result() as $row) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                return $data;
            }
            else {return NULL;}
        } else {return NULL;}

    }
```

check my code and tell me my mistakes Thanks in advance.

Error Shoe in View :

```
  A Database Error Occurred

  Error Number: 1052

  Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous

  SELECT `a`.`id`, `title`, `a`.`status`, `description`, `image`, `a`.`email`, `tags`, `postdate`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `rc` FROM (`articles` a) LEFT JOIN `users` u ON `u`.`email` = `a`.`email` WHERE `email` = 'admin@gmail.com' AND `a`.`status` = '1'

  Filename: F:\wamp\www\project\system\database\DB_driver.php

  Line Number: 331
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactored your code. Just copy-paste and check its working.

**Controller:**

```
public function user_article()
{   

    $rc = $this->input->get('rc');
    $data['title'] = "User Article";        
    if ($this->session->userdata ('is_logged_in'))
    {
        $data['profile']=$this->model_users->profilefetch();
        $data['results']=$this->article_m->u_article($rc);
        $this->load->view('sd/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('sd/user_article', $data);
        $this->load->view('sd/footer', $data);
    } 
    else 
    {

    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
function u_article($rc)
{  
    $query = $this->db->select('email')->where('rc',$rc)->get('users');
    $result = $query->result_array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        $row = $query->row_array(); 
        $array = array ('u.email' => $row['email'], 'a.status' => '1'); 
        $query1 = $this->db->select('a.id,a.title,a.status,a.description,a.image,a.email,a.tags,a.postdate,u.firstname,u.lastname,u.rc')->join('users u','u.email = a.email','left')->where($array)->get('articles a');

        if ($query1->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            foreach ($query1->result() as $row) 
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        else {return NULL;}
    } else {return NULL;}
}
```

Comment: Hello, This code is not work , $_GET is properly work , i think  this code create a problem ill add error message in my question u can chack ...  $array = array ('email' => $row['email'], 'a.status' => '1'); 
        $query1 = $this->db->select('a.id,title,a.status,description,image,a.email,tags,postdate,firstname,lastname,rc')->join('users u','u.email = a.email','left')->where($array)->get('articles a');

Comment: This error show in view : A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'

SELECT `a`.`id`, `title`, `a`.`status`, `description`, `image`, `a`.`email`, `tags`, `postdate`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `rc` FROM (`articles` a) LEFT JOIN `users` u ON `u`.`email` = `a`.`email` WHERE `0` = 'email' AND `1` = 'admin@gmail.com' AND `a`.`status` = '1'

Filename: F:\wamp\www\project\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331

Comment: Basically `$_GET['rc']` and `$this->input->get('rc')` are same. Its just the CI way of doing thing. `('email',  $row['email'], 'a.status' => '1')` there is a `comma` and it should `=>`

Comment: Error Change : Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: You have to add alias to all the columns. Like `u.email`, `a.title`

Comment: It's Work Thanks just add : $array = array ('u.email' => $row['email'], 'a.status' => '1');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83029/discussion-between-vijay-arora-and-parag-tyagi-morpheus).